# how to delete cookies?

Tags: php, cookies, setcookie

When I `print_r($_COOKIE);`, I get following result.

```
Array ( [filters] => Array ( [input1] => 1 [input2] => 20000 [input3] => none ) [PHPSESSID] => 12334 )
```

I want to delete some element and want it to be like this:

```
Array ( [filters] => Array ( [input3] => none ) [PHPSESSID] => 12334 )
```

I tried this but it not effecting anything in `$_COOKIE`

```
$past = time() - 3600;
setcookie( "filters[input1]", "", $past, '/' );
setcookie( "filters[input2]", "", $past, '/' );
```

What is wrong here? All day is waisted trying this?

Thanks

Comment: Make sure that setcookie is running before the headers are sent.

Comment: @Derek: headers? How to check and fix this. Please give me an example.

Comment: Also, make sure that the `$path` and `$domain` arguments match the `$path` and `$domain` that were used to set them in the first place

Comment: Before you call `setcookie` you can't have whitespace, e.g. `   <?php` or echo/print.

Comment: You can check if/where the headers were sent with [`headers_sent()`](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.headers-sent.php)

Comment: @Student Can you show us the code that set's the cookies in the first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
unset($_COOKIE['filters']['input1']);
unset($_COOKIE['filters']['input2']);
$time = time() + 1000; // enything you want, if its in the past $_COOKIE['filters'] will no loger exist
setcookie('filters', $_COOKIE['filters'], $time, '/' );
```

Comment: But when I refreshed the page, the cookies are back.

Comment: What code did you use to initially set the 'filters' cookie?
this seems to be caused by "setcookie('filters', $_COOKIE['filters'], $time, '/' );" not functioning well to save the cookie.. Did you send your page's headers before this function call?

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure that you call `setcookie()` to delete the cookie with the same arguments (path, secure, etc) as you did to create the cookie?

Also, `setcookie()` does not affect `$_COOKIE` in the running script. Only subsequent calls to that script will have the modified `$_COOKIE` array. To remove values from `$_COOKIE` in the same session, call `unset($_COOKIE['name'])`.

Answer (score 1):

You must reload the page after your run setcookie() - the result of your setting cookie is not available until you reload the page. Also try using 'older' time - older than 1 hour - try like a year in the past. Some browsers will not delete cookie if the time is not far enough in the past

Answer (score 0):

If you created your cookies with a domain , you may need to remove then using the same domain name. 
i.e.

to set a cookie:

```
setcookie('mycookie', 'value', time() + 999, '/', '.my.domain', false);
```

to delete cookie:

```
 setcookie('mycookie', "", -1, '/', '.my.domain', false);
```